# How to get Temporal.Duration from two Temporal.Instant in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-temporal

I have two `Instant` objects, and need to get one `Duration` object. How would I do this in JavaScript?

```js
const start = Temporal.now.instant();
await doLongOperation();
const finish = Temporal.now.instant();

const duration = ... ?
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but I wouldn't recommend using Temporal.Now.instant() to time a long-running operation. Now.instant() basically gives you the system clock time, which can be changed by the user or by an NTP update while the operation is ongoing, and browsers may choose to lower the resolution of the clock for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `.until()` or `.since()` methods of a `Temporal.Instant` object.

Until:

```js
const duration = start.until(finish);
```

Since:

```js
const duration = finish.since(start);
```